# How to build and operate a master Notebook?

Tags: notebooks

Suppose you have some notebooks, they work for a family of related tasks, each one doing a certain task. Lets say Notebook 1 gets two inputs from its variables `in11` and `in12`, and produces one output to `out1`. The other Notebook 2 gets two inputs from  its variables `in21` and `in22`, and produces one output to `out2`.

How can we set up a kind of master notebook where just the decision to select a specific
task should be made, the assignments to the variables are made, and the result of the calculation is shown. The two working notebooks themselves should be in the same folder on your disk, and a call from the open master notebook pipes them their respective inputs and outputs.

Comment: Any specific reason for not using a package?

Answer (score 6):

Simple example. In `nb1.nb` put, say, the Input cell:

```
in11 = "In 11  ";
in12 = "In 12";
out1 = Row[{in11, in12}]
```

And in `nb2.nb` put the Input cell:

```
in21 = "In 21  ";
in22 = "In 22";
out2 = Row[{in21, in22}]
```

In `master.nb` put the Input cell:

```
dir = NotebookDirectory[];
NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{dir, "nb1.nb"}]];
NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{dir, "nb2.nb"}]];
Column[{out1, out2}]
```

Save all three notebooks in the same directory (or modify the code in `master.nb` accordingly). Then evaluating that cell in `master.nb` will produce

```
In 11  In 12
In 21  In 22
```

which means, of course, that the Input cells in both `nb1.nb` and `nb2.nb` have been evaluated, so that values have been given to `out1` and `out2`, respectively.

Comment: I like this.  .   .And if you want to pass some variable values from nb1.nb to master.nb in the first place? .  .  .So the master.nb acts like a function.  .  .Get a value and return a value.

Comment: What makes all this work is the fact that, by default, all values set in one notebook are available to all other notebooks at the same Mathematica kernel session. (Unless you take steps to restrict the `Context` of a notebook.)