# How to automate repetitive evaluation of a notebook from a parent notebook

Tags: notebooks, automation

I've got a code that I want to automate, but I'm not sure how.  I have a Mathematica notebook that I need to run many times over, each time changing one variable and repeating.  My idea was to set up a "parent" notebook with a For loop that changes the variable each time, and the main notebook is called each time inside the For loop.  However, I think this involves parallel Mathematica computing, and I'm new to this.  I tried to tell the "parent" notebook to Pause[] while the other notebook is running, but that pauses both notebooks and nothing gets done.  Help?!

Here's some example code:

```
For[i=1,i<7,i++,
 For[j=1,j<7,j++,

(* lots of inputs dependent on i and j *)

nb=NotebookOpen["Sanple.nb"]; SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook]; SelectionEvaluate[nb];

];];
```

What I need my code to do is to open Sample.nb, evaluate it for the current i and j, and then wait for that evaluation to be done before moving on to the next i and j.  Sample.nb is the core algorithm that I need to run many times (gonna be hundreds), so this loop will definitely help out.

Comment: I think a more concrete example will help us greatly in helping you.

Comment: If you can give a minimum example of what you seek, we can help you.  Nevertheless, from what you state, it appears that all can be done within a single notebook with an iterator.  We await your code.

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully it makes more sense.  I guess I'm trying to treat another notebook as a subroutine, but I'm not sure how Mathematica does that.

Comment: I removed the parallel tag and changed the title (your goal does not seem to involve any parallel computing). In any case, you should look into: [Creating Mathematica packages](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/creating-mathematica-packages) which will save you a lot of hassle in the long run.

Comment: [related: 33197](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33197/5478)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.  I think it should work.  Much appreciated!

Comment: The answer is use `NotebookEvaluate` per the linked question. The behavior of @Hogy88's (reasonable looking) attempt is interesting however. It blasts through the loop first, essentially queuing up the requested evaluation(s) to perform afterwards. (hence the appearance of some sort of parallel behavior)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Per [george2079's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) recommendation and [Yves Klett's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/131/yves-klett) reference to
[How to build and operate a master Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22068/how-to-build-and-operate-a-master-notebook),
I think this is better closed as a duplicate or not at all, since it is a slight extension of the linked Q&A.  There may be times when iterating a notebook is useful.  At this time, it's hard for me to imagine how the computation wouldn't be better accomplished by a package, as Yves recommended in another comment, or sometimes just by a function.  Nonetheless, here is an example:

Suppose this notebook is saved in "Sample.nb":

```
sampleNB = 
 Notebook[{Cell[
    BoxData[RowBox[{"res", " ", "=", " ", 
       RowBox[{"{", 
         RowBox[{"res", ",", 
           RowBox[{"f", "[", RowBox[{"i", ",", "j"}], "]"}]}], 
         "}"}]}]], "Input"]}]
```

Suppose further it is opened with `nb = NotebookOpen["Sample.nb"]`; then the result will be equivalent to

```
nb = NotebookPut[sampleNB];
```

Then we can iterate evaluation of the notebook with the following:

```
Block[{res = {}},
 Do[NotebookEvaluate[nbobj], {i, 3}, {j, 2}];
 Flatten@res] (* Caveat: Flatten won't work right if the value of `f` has the head List *)

(*  {f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[3, 1], f[3, 2]}  *)
```