# Import another Notebook as if it were a Package

Tags: import, notebooks, packages, scoping

Is it possible to import the contents of another (existing) notebook into the current namespace in the same way that I can with a package?

I know that it would be best to use a `.m` or `.wl` file, and I know that they can be created from `.nb`, but I would like to avoid the hassle of having people doing these and I would like th ability to load directly a `.nb`.

For example, consider this scenario:

#### `data.nb` / `data.wl`

```
test = "This is a test";
x = f[2,4];
```

#### `master.nb`

```
f[a_, b_] := a^b;
Get[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.nb"];
Print[test];
Print[x];
```

As that stand, evaluating `master.nb` results in:

> test
>
> x

On the other hand, if I `Get` the `data.wl` file instead, I get the desired output:

> This is a test
>
> 16

There is a solution that uses `NotebookEvaluate` instead of `Get` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22077/2440)) but it requires the context of each notebook to be global and thus will fail for anyone who has set each notebooks' context to be independent of each other.

So how can I load a `.nb` file in such a way that it behaves like a package file?

Comment: You can temporarily change `CellContext` of the notebook.

Comment: @Kuba Do you mean, open `data.nb` and modify the `CellContext` property manually?  Or is there a way that this can be done programmatically?

Comment: You can use `SetOptions` or `CurrentValue`.

Comment: @Kuba So using `Get`, I get a `Notebook` object, but I'm not sure how I can manipulate it and use `SetOptions` :/  Mathematica's documentation on this is rather limited too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can temporarily change `CellContext` of the notebook with `SetOptions` or `CurrentValue` but if the notebook isn't opened yet, this is faster:

```
Module[{path, nb}
   ,
   path = (*path*);

   nb = NotebookOpen[ path, CellContext -> "Global`", Visible -> False];

   NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> False];

   NotebookClose[nb]
]
```

You can use `$Context` instead of `` "Global`" `` for general case.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly with `$Context` :)